# Select default value with condition in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have an angular app with the following array:

```
countries = [{"code": "ZA", "name": "South Africa"}, {"code": "CH", "name": "Switzerland"}]
```

with a Jade select as follow:

```
select(ng-model='myCountry', ng-options='country.name for country in countries')
```

What I would like to do is to pre-select a country based on the code for example:

```
select(ng-model='myCountry', ng-options='country.name for country in countries', ng-selected='country.code=="CH"')
```

Obviously, this solution doesn't work as ng-selected is not intended to be used in a select but in an option tag.

It is important for me to use a conditional selection and not a default index value like in the [angularJS example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample above it looks like you should do this in your controller:

```
$scope.myCountry = $scope.countries.filter(function(c){ return  c.code==="CH"})[0];
```

Like this:

```
<script>
  function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{"code": "ZA", "name": "South Africa"}, {"code": "CH", "name": "Switzerland"}];
    $scope.myCountry = $scope.countries.filter(function(c){ return  c.code==="CH"})[0];
  }
  </script>
```

Or you could try building the select with and `ngRepeat` which seems to be closer to what you need, like this:

[**Online Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhsRvmqQdzoAfLyLU1LM?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="">
    <script>
  function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{"code": "ZA", "name": "South Africa"}, {"code": "CH", "name": "Switzerland"}];      
  }
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">    
    <select ng-model="myCountry" >
      <option ng-selected="c.code=='CH'" ng-repeat="c in countries">{{c.name}}</option>
    </select><br>
  {{myCountry |json}}
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please develop this solution? I'm new to angular and don't know that much about filters...

Comment: @ncohen I added a couple of samples. Hope they help

Answer (score 1):

That is what ng-model is for. I suggest you initialize myCountry in a controller. Note that myCountry should ideally have the same format as countries (eg: `{"code": "ZA", "name": "South Africa"}`).

Edit: I am adding an example from my own project:

```
<select class="small" data-ng-change="goToTask(current_task.id)" data-ng-model="current_task" data-ng-options="task.name for task in tasks track by task.id"></select>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.current_task = { id: $scope.myService.getCurrentTaskId() };
```

What is important here is that current_task is at minimum a hash containing the `id` key.

Edit2: I was thinking about the sorting problem with the track by. I think you can use `select` instead, eg: `ng-options="select country.code as country.name for country in countries". I haven't tried it but from the angular docs, it should work.

Comment: It means going in a loop again which is not ideal...ng-options already does this loop, can I take advantage of it?

Comment: @ncohen which loop? `ng-model` is in your select tag.

Comment: to initialize myCountry in the controller, I need to go over each country and check if the country has to be selected

Comment: @ncohen no I am pretty sure all you need to do is `$scope.myCountry = { code: 'CH' };`

Comment: as you said, myCountry has the same format meaning that Switzerland has to appear in myCountry...as you can imagine Switzerland can have different spelling based on languages

Comment: @ncohen, you don't need all the information in the selector, just the `code` will do. I was saying you should keep the same format because you can't just do `myCountry= 'CH'`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work... I get no pre-selection. Here is what I did in my ctrl: $scope.myCountry={}; $scope.myCountry.code='CH';

Comment: @ncohen, I just noticed you are missing the `track by` in `ng-options`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54469/discussion-between-alex-c-and-ncohen).